# Как изменить кнопку close в fancybox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, fancybox

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.fancybox.open({
        src: '#hidden',
        type: 'inline',
        clickSlide : 'false',
        clickOutside : 'false',
        touch: false,
        closeBtn: false,
        autoScale: true,
        transitionIn: 'none',
        transitionOut: 'none',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fancyboxmodal {
    display: none;
    width: 896px;
}
.ice_karts {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 34px;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.045em;
    color: #222222;

}

.fios {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.mailkarts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 796px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;

}

.phonekarts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.datekarts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.date_before_karts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.inputskarts\> {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputskarts\> input {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}


.buttonkarts {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 230px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    color: #222222;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    border: 1px solid #BA905B;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.buttonkarts:hover {
    background: #BA905B;
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

.formscheckeds {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.checkboxsmodal {
    /* border: 1px solid #3E3E3E; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -27px;
    border: 1px solid #BA905B;
}


.checked:checked + .checkboxsmodal:before {
    content: "";
    background: #BA905B;
    padding: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.checks {
    color: #AEAEAE;
    padding-left: 62px;
}

@media (max-width: 863px) {

    .formscheckeds {

        margin-top: 23px;
        margin-left: -36px;
    }
}

.datepicker {
    z-index: 1000000000000 !important;
}


.datepicker--nav-action {
    width: 32px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.datepicker--nav-action svg {
    width: 16px !important;
    height: 8px !important;
}

.datepicker--nav-action path {
    /* fill: none; */
    stroke: #9c9c9c;
    stroke-width: 1px !important;
}


.datepicker--day-name {
    color: #A5A5A5 !important;
}


.datepicker--cell.-selected-, .datepicker--cell.-selected-.-current- {
    color: black !important;
    background: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #BA905B !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}


.datepicker--cell.-current- {
    color: #BA905B !important;
}

.fancybox-button   {
    display: none !important;
}


.buttonsfancy {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<div class="fancyboxmodal" id="hidden">
    <h2 class="ice_karts"></h2>
        <button  onclick="$.fancybox.close(); return false;" class="buttonsfancy"><span>×</span></button>
        <div class="inputskarts>">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ФИО" class="fios">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Телефон" class="phonekarts">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email для связи" class="mailkarts">
            <div class="datelols">
            <input type="text"  placeholder="Дата начала заморозки" class="datekarts datepicker-here">
            <input type="text" class="date_before_karts datepicker-here" placeholder="Конечная дата">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modalbutton">
            <button class="buttonkarts" id="">Заморозить карту</button>
        </div>
        <div class="formscheckeds">
            <label class="checks">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checked">
                <span class="checkboxsmodal"></span>
                Согласие на обработку персональных данных</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <li class="header_item">
                        <a href="#modal" id="btn" class="header_link">Нажми на меня</a>
                    </li>
```

fancybox не даёт закинуть кнопку за пределы ширины самого модального, как вынести её? position: fixed не использовать

Answer (score 2):

Так?

Для просмотра: Выполнить код -> На всю страницу

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $.fancybox.open({
        src: '#hidden',
        type: 'inline',
        clickSlide : 'false',
        clickOutside : 'false',
        touch: false,
        closeBtn: false,
        autoScale: true,
        transitionIn: 'none',
        transitionOut: 'none',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.fancyboxmodal {
    display: none;
    width: 896px;
}
.ice_karts {
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 34px;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.045em;
    color: #222222;

}

.fios {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.mailkarts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 796px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;

}

.phonekarts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.datekarts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.date_before_karts {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 383px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EDEDED;
}

.inputskarts\> {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inputskarts\> input {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}


.buttonkarts {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 230px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
    color: #222222;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    border: 1px solid #BA905B;
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat-Regular';
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.buttonkarts:hover {
    background: #BA905B;
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

.formscheckeds {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.checkboxsmodal {
    /* border: 1px solid #3E3E3E; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -27px;
    border: 1px solid #BA905B;
}


.checked:checked + .checkboxsmodal:before {
    content: "";
    background: #BA905B;
    padding: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.checks {
    color: #AEAEAE;
    padding-left: 62px;
}

@media (max-width: 863px) {

    .formscheckeds {

        margin-top: 23px;
        margin-left: -36px;
    }
}

.datepicker {
    z-index: 1000000000000 !important;
}


.datepicker--nav-action {
    width: 32px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.datepicker--nav-action svg {
    width: 16px !important;
    height: 8px !important;
}

.datepicker--nav-action path {
    /* fill: none; */
    stroke: #9c9c9c;
    stroke-width: 1px !important;
}


.datepicker--day-name {
    color: #A5A5A5 !important;
}


.datepicker--cell.-selected-, .datepicker--cell.-selected-.-current- {
    color: black !important;
    background: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #BA905B !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
}


.datepicker--cell.-current- {
    color: #BA905B !important;
}

.fancybox-button   {
    display: none !important;
}


.buttonsfancy {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

/*EDIT*/
.buttonsfancy {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: -60px;
    top: 0;
}
.fancybox-content {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
/*EDIT*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<div class="fancyboxmodal" id="hidden">
    <h2 class="ice_karts"></h2>
        <button  onclick="$.fancybox.close(); return false;" class="buttonsfancy"><span>×</span></button>
        <div class="inputskarts>">
            <input type="text" placeholder="ФИО" class="fios">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Телефон" class="phonekarts">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email для связи" class="mailkarts">
            <div class="datelols">
            <input type="text"  placeholder="Дата начала заморозки" class="datekarts datepicker-here">
            <input type="text" class="date_before_karts datepicker-here" placeholder="Конечная дата">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modalbutton">
            <button class="buttonkarts" id="">Заморозить карту</button>
        </div>
        <div class="formscheckeds">
            <label class="checks">
                <input type="checkbox" class="checked">
                <span class="checkboxsmodal"></span>
                Согласие на обработку персональных данных</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     <li class="header_item">
                        <a href="#modal" id="btn" class="header_link">Нажми на меня</a>
                    </li>
```